# How can you read style attributes from cells and assign them back dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sorting

I have a sort routine that reads the rows of a given table, sorts them and displays them back in sorted order. It works fine except for one thing, all formatting disappears in the process.

The relevant code is:

```
function newSortTable(myTable)
    {

    var table, rows;
    var x = [[],[]];

    table = document.getElementById(myTable);
    rows = table.rows;
    var numRows = table.rows.length;
    var numCols = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
        {
        var y = [];
        for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
            y[j] = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;

        x[i-1] = y;
        }

    numRows = rows.length;
    for (var k = numRows-1; k > 0; k--)
        table.deleteRow(k);

    x.sort();

    for (var l = 0; l < numRows-1; l++)
        {
        var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        for (var m = 0; m < numCols; m++)
            {
            var myCell = newRow.insertCell(m);
            $(myCell).html(x[l][m]).css({"background-color":"white"});
            }
        }

    } // function newSortTable(myTable)
```

I apply a white background in the code:

> .css({"background-color":"white"})

which applies to all cells but I would like a way of reading and storing the .CSS style of each cell and applying it back when I re-display the form. One example of such formatting might be:

> .css({"textAlign":"right","paddingRight":"1em"});

but changes mostly with field types.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `css()` command to apply to the whole document, take your jQuery and apply it as so:

```
$(document).css({"background-color":"white"})
```

That is the affect you are describing.  However, to apply it to just one element, simply do `$(element).css(...)`, and only that element will have it changed.  So, *it should just work as you have described without further changes*.

But you are doing it on...

```
var myCell = newRow.insertCell(m);
$(myCell).html(x[l][m]).css({"background-color":"white"});
```

What is the result of `insertCell()`?  Is it the string `"*"`, because that would then match all elements?  Without knowing what `myCell` is, it's impossible to say why `css()` would be failing on it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not my question. I know how to assign .CSS to particular cells or rows, but what I want to be able to do is to take any table passed to the sort routine and read the style associated with each cell, save it somehow and then when I rewrite the table, apply the .CSS again. I just don't know to read and store the .CSS - I do know how to apply it. Does that make sense? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, Philip.  So, when you say you redisplay the form, I am guessing you manually rebuild a table from scratch, and you want the rebuild procedure to remember the old styles?  If so, it depends on what data in the table is changing -- can you just make an object `{}` and store element `id`:`{css:value}`, and then when table is done, `$(table).find('#thatid').css('somecss', 'somevalue')`?  I think how you're building that table may be key.

Comment: See above. I actually just want to keep the existing .CSS which I was able to do by not rewriting the whole table and simply rewriting the contents of each cell. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem by leaving the table with the formatting as it is and not deleting all rows apart from the header. That simplifies the code and does not require any changing of .CSS. Here is the revised code:

```
function newSortTable(myTable)
    {
    var x = [[],[]];
    var table = document.getElementById(myTable);
    var rows = table.rows;
    var numRows = table.rows.length;
    var numCols = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++)
        {
        var y = [];

        // Store the row into the array y
        for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++) y[j] = table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;

        // Add array y to array of rows x
        x[i-1] = y;
        }

    // Sort the array by the values in the first column
    x.sort();

    // Now write back the rows in sorted order
    for (var l = 0; l < numRows-1; l++)
        {
        for (var m = 0; m < numCols; m++)
            {
            var myCell = table.rows[l+1].cells[m];
            $(myCell).html(x[l][m]);
            }
        }

    } // function newSortTable(myTable)
```

Thanks for all of your help.